# What are the drawbacks to using mod_log_rotate and rotatelogs.exe together?

Tags: windows, logging, configuration, apache-2.4

On Microsoft-based platforms, are there any drawbacks or hidden pitfalls to using rotatelogs.exe for ErrorLog directive(s) and allowing mod_log_rotate to handle CustomLog directives for rotation? As I understand it, mod_log_rotate takes over logging duties server-wide, so how do mod_log_rotate and rotatelogs.exe interact? Is rotatelogs.exe piped data from mod_log_rotate?

Below is the configuration I have in httpd.conf:

```
# Rotate our ErrorLogs, since mod_log_rotate doesn't seem to handle this.
ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -l logs/error/error.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S.log 86400"
[...]
<IfModule log_rotate_module>
#
# Produce a log file with at human readable extension in a directory called 'access'.
#
CustomLog logs/access/access_log.%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S combined
[...]
```

I am not asking for opinions, particularly if they are off-topic. I would like to know if this will produce any real problems from a technical or security stand-point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rotatelogs` and `mod_log_rotate` are two different solutions to the same problem (Rotating logs without having to signal or restart Apache).

`rotatelogs` (or other programs like [`cronolog`](http://cronolog.org)) solves the problem by piping the Apache log to a program which handles the rotation. This is a fine solution, though it means running another process and keeping pipes open.

`mod_log_rotate` solves the problem by handling the rotation in the server process. Again, also a fine solution, but it *only* rotates the access logs (which leaves you needing to do something else for the error log).

There's nothing "wrong" with using both solutions (one to handle your access log, one to handle your error log), but for the sake of sanity and consistency I would stick to one solution - either signaling Apache when you rotate logs, or piping everything to `rotatelogs`.

---

In particular on Windows, I would suggest rotating your logs externally and signaling Apache, because [piping stuff around on Windows can be buggy](http://www.sitebuddy.com/Apache/Rotatelogs.exe/Bug) (and to my knowledge the situation hasn't improved much since 2006).

(Actually were I making a recommendation I would recommend *not running Apache on Windows* -- Apache is designed to run on Unix servers, IIS is designed to run on Windows servers, and never should the two cross despite what the Apache people might claim about "supporting" Windows.)

Comment: @vorteq7 Thanks again. This was exactly the answer I was looking for. :-)